# Roblox friend deleter

Tags: python, roblox

Im making a program that uses cookie to log in roblox account and delete all friends, it seems that it does scrape the user ids correctly and prints them out if deletion succeeded, but it does not actually delete anyone, Im new to python and I cant think of a fix for this

```
import requests
import time

cookie = input('Enter cookie: ')

req = requests.Session()
req.cookies['.ROBLOSECURITY'] = cookie

try:
    userid = req.get('https://www.roblox.com/mobileapi/userinfo').json()['UserID']

except:
    input('invalid cookie given')

    exit()

print('\nlogged in\n')

friends = req.get(f'https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/{userid}/friends').json()

friendlist = {}

for friend in friends["data"]:

    friendlist[friend["id"]] = friend

for friend in friendlist:
    try:
        r = req.post(f'https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/{friend}/unfriend')

        print(f'deleted friend - {friend}')

    except:
        print('error')

time.sleep(999)
```

Comment: I would imagine those websites have anti bot protection, meaning you at the very least need to use selenium, and even then it might not work.

Comment: Try using the developer tools inside your browser to see what is sent when you unfriend someone. There may be more than just posting to the URL and there might be some data posted too.

Comment: don't use a bare `except`, at least have `except Exception as e: print(e)` so that you know what error was raised, but best is to except what you expect

Comment: I added the 'except Exception as e: print(e)' code, it doesnt seem to throw any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. I made something like this to unfollow everyone except for terminated users.

Try my script that should unfriend everyone:

```
import requests,json,time

cookie = "cookie here"

while True:
    with requests.session() as session:
        session.cookies[".ROBLOSECURITY"] = cookie
        header = session.post("https://catalog.roblox.com/")
        session.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"] = header.headers["X-CSRF-TOKEN"]
        session.headers["Origin"] = "https://www.roblox.com/"
        session.headers["Referer"] = "https://www.roblox.com/"
    user = session.get("https://www.roblox.com/mobileapi/userinfo").json()
    friends = session.get("https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/{0}/friends".format(user["UserID"])).json()
    if len(friends["data"]) > 0:
        for friend in friends["data"]:
            response = session.post("https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/{0}/unfriend".format(friend["id"])).json()
            print(response)
    else:
        print("everyone has been unfriended")
        break
```

[image]

edit: I had a look at your script and it seems like you forgot to validate the session with an X-CSRF-TOKEN.